# Download file with PHP and Curl, without knowing the file full path

Tags: php, file, curl, download

I need some help with the following problem.
I my php web page I need to download a excel file from a web, but I don't have the file path, the download start when I enter in the url link, for example: www.example.com/prices.
Entering in that url the download begin.
Any help with this? 
I dont triyed with curl. any code to help?

```
//DESCARGA DE ARCHIVO
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);     
$url = "http://www.distribuidoraidem.com.ar/precios";
$filecontent = file_get_contents($url);
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),"tmpxls");
file_put_contents($tmpfname,$filecontent);
```

Previously I made a login in the web with curl, so if you try the code  will not work. 
Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code that you tried

Comment: If you make a cURL request to a page that attempts to download a file form a different source, then cURL will attempt to download that file as well. Just point your cURL request to `www.example.com/prices`.

Comment: Check out `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` at php.net/curl_setopt which you can use in your curl request to follow the redirect to the actual download.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'www.example.com/prices');
    $fp = fopen('prices.xlsx', 'w+');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: but the name of the file changes every days, I doesnt know his name

Comment: Seems like you could make the name on your side whatever you like.  I would add a date to the file like this: fopen('prices-'. date("Y-m-d") .'.xlsx', 'w+');

Comment: It's not possible that way. the filename changes not all days. If try only whit the extension? or this function need al the fullname?